# How to Repeat Previous Actions in Exception in EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, tracking, repeat, savechanges

I am having a problem with repeating previous operations when there is an error in the `SaveChanges` method of `Entity Framework.`

Below is the code block

```
 public static int SaveChangesTask(this DbContext db)
    {
        int result = -1;int countLoop = 0;
        bool continueLoop = true;
        var modifiedOrAddedEntities = db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(a => a.State != EntityState.Detached
           && a.State != EntityState.Unchanged).ToList();
        while (continueLoop && countLoop<3)
        {

            try
            {
                result= db.SaveChanges();
                continueLoop = false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.ToSystemException();
                if(error.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("ORA-00060".ToLowerInvariant()) || error.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("deadlock"))
                {

                    foreach (var item in modifiedOrAddedEntities)
                    {
                        db.Entry(item).State = item.State;
                    }
                    countLoop++;
                    Random rnd = new Random();

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(1, 5)* 1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But when I want to add old tracking objects to context, Entity Framework Throws Exception like that
"`The entity type DbEntityEntry is not part of the model for the current context`"

Comment: I figured out that I used the wrong object .When I changed  cote block from "db.Entry(item).State = item.State;"  to " db.Entry(item.Entity).State = item.State;" , Error corrected